# Sort a geopandas dataframe by location

Tags: linestring, geopandas

I have a geopandas DataFrame (created from a shapefile) which represents the course of a public transport vessel.

Exemplary DataFrame:

`| oid | geometry            |
|-----|---------------------|
|  1  | LineString(1 1, 1 2)|
|  2  | LineString(2 3, 3 4)|
|  3  | LineString(1 2, 2 3)|
|  4  | LineString(3 4, 5 6)|`

The DataFrame contains segments of LineStrings in no given order of the object id `oid`. How can I sort the LineString segments by location to have the joined course segment by segment in geographic order (from example data I want to get the order 1 -> 3 -> 2 -> 4)?

I other words, I want to find the touchpoints row-wise.

Background: I have another DataFrame where I have a measured variable given only by the distance from the starting point of the course (of course along this course) and no GIS information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a multiline, merge it and split into lines again:

```or-tag-here
from shapely import geometry, ops
import geopandas as gpd

line1 = geometry.LineString([(1, 1), (1, 2)])
line2 = geometry.LineString([(2, 3), (3, 4)])
line3 = geometry.LineString([(1, 2), (2, 3)])
line4 = geometry.LineString([(3, 4), (5, 6), (8,9)])

df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[line1,line2,line3,line4])

multitline = geometry.MultiLineString(df.geometry.tolist())
merged = ops.linemerge(multitline)

startstop = []
for line in multitline:
    coords = [c for c in line.coords]
    startstop.append((coords[0],coords[:-1]))

collection = ops.split(merged, geometry.MultiPoint(startstop))

df2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[line for line in Collection])
```

Results:

```
df
                     geometry
0       LINESTRING (1 1, 1 2)
1       LINESTRING (2 3, 3 4)
2       LINESTRING (1 2, 2 3)
3  LINESTRING (3 4, 5 6, 8 9)
df2
                     geometry
0       LINESTRING (1 1, 1 2)
1       LINESTRING (1 2, 2 3)
2       LINESTRING (2 3, 3 4)
3  LINESTRING (3 4, 5 6, 8 9)
```

Comment: Thanks!! Can I split the union into evenly distances, say 100m?

Comment: With my data I get the error `
NotImplementedError: Multi-part geometries do not provide a coordinate sequence`, have to figure out how your sample data is different

Comment: That error means that one of your lines is a MultiLineString, so you will have to go line by line, check if there is a MultiLineString, and then by segments in feature['geometry']['coordinates'] convert it to LineStrings

Comment: type() of element in 1st row says `shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString`. But I'll have to check all lines..

Comment: @AndiAnderle: `all(isinstance(x, type(geometry.linestring.LineString)) for x in df.geometry.tolist())` will return true if all geometries in df is linestring

Comment: Strange, if I do ``u6_gdf.geometry.tolist()`` I get ``[<shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x1fff69fa2e8>,
 <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x1fff69fa7f0>,...`` but your code snippet says all ``False``..

Comment: I guess I know the problem. ``ops.linemerge`` should return a LineString, but it returns a MultiLineString. The docstring says this happens when MultiLines are not contiguous...

Comment: I see! I flattened the MultiLineString manually ``multicoords = [list(line.coords) for line in multiline]`` and ``simplecoords = shapely.geometry.MultiPoint([item for sublist in multicoords  for item in sublist])`` and the MultiPoint does the trick! NICE!!

Comment: But still, if I want to connect the points back again to a line, they get weirdly connected, as they are not in the correct order along the track :-(. Think I have to arrange them in their closest order.

Comment: @AndiAnderle i have changed the code, it did not work properly on linestrings with more than two vertices. I dont know if it will make any difference on your data though.

Comment: Thank you so much! The linemerge does the trick with merging the lines in the correct order. My problem is, that linemerge does not work for me as my geodata from the track is not contiguos and linemerge does nothing.